# Reference request: showing that solution of an Ito SDE stays bounded with positive probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Assume that we have a (well-posed) Ito SDE of the form $$\mathrm{d} X_t = b(X_t)\,\mathrm{d} t + \sigma(X_t)\,\mathrm{d}W_t \label{1}\tag{1},$$ where $b \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$, $\sigma \colon \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d$, and $W_t$ is a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion. I am wondering under what kind of assumptions on the drift $b$ and the diffusion $\sigma$ can we show that $$\mathbb{P}\left(\sup_{t\geq 0} \|X_t\| \leq R\right) > 0$$ for some constant $R < \infty$? Or in other words, under what kind of assumptions on the drift $b$ and the diffusion $\sigma$ can we show that there is a positive probability such that the trajectory of $X_t$ does not leave some large enough balls? Currently I am only aware of the so-called **Stroock-Varadhan support theorem** showing that solutions of certain Ito SDEs stay within certain (large enough) finite balls almost surely for all time. But I am not aware of any literature which are related to my question. I would appreciate any pointers to contemporary research papers or lecture notes.

Comment: You could also try Malliavin calculus. Namely to possibly obtain a density for the supremum of the SDE.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Malliavin calculus and hence I would prefer a "SDE approach" rather than a PDE (or SPDE) approach...

Answer (score 5):

The monograph *Stochastic Stability of Differential Equations* by Khasminskii may be useful here. On page 22 in chapter 1, he defines various notions of stability that in particular imply your condition. The conditions for such notions to hold are discussed later in the book, you may choose which one suits your purpose best.

Comment: Thank you very much Nate, I will take a look at the suggested monograph!